# Error with firebase_messaging plugin in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task`':firebase_messaging:processDebugGoogleServices'`

  > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
  >   Searched Location: 
  >   /Users/macbookair/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.1.6/android/src/nullnull/google-services.json
  >   /Users/macbookair/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.1.6/android/src/debug/google-services.json
  >   /Users/macbookair/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.1.6/android/src/nullnullDebug/google-services.json
  >   /Users/macbookair/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.1.6/android/src/nullnull/debug/google-services.json
  >   /Users/macbookair/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.1.6/android/src/debug/nullnull/google-services.json
  >   /Users/macbookair/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-5.1.6/android/google-services.json
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23sGradle task `assembleDebug` failed with exit code 1

Comment: added google-services.json in android/app folder still showing json file not found error in flutter

Comment: Srikanth, please write decision of problem here, if it is. Thanks!